# Is it possible to convert an external hard disk to a NAS with just a USB to Ethernet adaptor?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, usb, nas

I have an ethernet to USB adaptor(like this - [https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN-Ethernet-Adapter-Nintendo-Chromebook/dp/B00MYT481C/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1534861393&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=ethernet+to+usb&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MYT481C) ), a spare female to female USB, and I had a spare router and an external hard disk I barely use. I had the idea to try to put it all together and convert the HDD into a NAS

I am not sure if this is possible, one of my concerns is that would the ethernet cable supply power to the disk. Any idea on whether it can be done or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. An external USB disk does not know how to "talk" over that kind of adaptor and it will not work.

Those adaptors are designed for devices that already know how to use them such as a PC, a Nintendo Switch or any other USB Host capable device such as a phone with USB OTG support.

Your external drive almost certainly does not support such an adaptor.

Many newer routers do have a USB port and can accept a USB hard drive and have it appear on the network. A Raspberry Pi can be combined with a USB hard drive to make a makeshift NAS as well.